# MySQL - Fetch comments and JOIN replies

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm trying to fetch both comments and replies of an article via one query using JOINs however not sure how to write it, so far I've got the comments but whenever I try to fetch the replies it stays within the same depth of the array so I'm not sure if this is going to work.

**comments structure:**

`id | article_ID | user | text`

**replies structure:**

`id | comment_ID | user | text`

Here's the query I have so far:

```
SELECT c.text, u.username, cr.text AS reply
FROM comments c 
LEFT JOIN user u
ON c.user = u.id
LEFT JOIN comments_replies cr 
ON cr.comment_ID = c.id
WHERE c.article_ID = :postID
```

This is the output of the result dump:

```
[0]=>
object(stdClass) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(7) "Comment"
    ["username"]=>
    string(5) "Woody"
    ["reply"]=>
    string(5) "reply"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(7) "Comment"
    ["username"]=>
    string(5) "Woody"
    ["reply"]=>
    NULL
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
[0]=>
object(stdClass) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(7) "Comment"
    ["username"]=>
    string(5) "Woody"
    ["comments"]=>
        [0]=>
            replier's username
            replier's text
        [1]=>
            replier's username
            replier's text
}
```

I'd prefer if this was possible with one query rather than using multiple queries or additional PHP code e.g. loops.